Getting JWT from Clerk in my React+Next.js app to test API calls using Curl
I have a Next.js + React app. I have an existing API defined in src/app/api/feature/route.ts. I want to use a command like curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/feature -d '{"key": "value"}' -H "Content-type: application/json" to test the endpoint manually from command line. In route.ts we get the Clerk JWT using:
  const { isSignedIn } = await clerkClient.authenticateRequest(req, {
    jwtKey: process.env.CLERK_JWT_KEY,
  });

  if (!isSignedIn) {
    return Response.json({
      "errorMessage": "Invalid JWT provided in Authorization header!"
    }, {
      status: 401
    });
  }

So when I run that POST command, I get the error message: {"errorMessage":"Invalid JWT provided in Authorization header!"}
So, looks like I need the JWT that Clerk generated when I logged into the app in the UI. How do I do that, if that's even the right approach or possible?

You can log to console the JWT: console.log(request.headers.get('Authorization'));
You should see something like Bearer <JWT> printed off
